# httpurlconnection post empty json

Tags: android, json, linux, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post JSON string to Linux server. However, it always says that no JSON object could be decoded. Back when I was testing at local host 10.0.2.2:5000. I can always get JSON object.

Is there anything I can do to make it work? Thank you.

The error is shown as below:
*ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded*

Update: I think it has something to do with my android permission. In my manifest file, I've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Is there any other lines that I should've added to make the post request work?

***To answer my own question:***

**Well, I've just resolved the problem. It turns out that I have to add one line:**
**This works.**

Here is my code:

```
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    conn.connect();
```

Comment: Often servers and clients checks the mime type of requests and responds before parsing. E.g. sending a JSON object with a text/plain MIME type will often result in an error simply because the client/server has no idea that the content is actually JSON. Are you sure that you have set the correct MIME type?

Comment: post you code where you connect to the server

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Please have a look at the code. Thanks

Comment: @Dyrborg But when I post the JSON to local host, it worked well.

Comment: @Zhiya You should post your answer as an answer, not in your question ;)

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks, Joffrey. I'll modify the code.

Comment: @Zhiya I meant create an answer to your own post and accept it, do not add your answer to your question post via editing. People who will search later won't see the question as accepted when browsing the list if you don't do so.

Comment: Oh, I tried that, but it says that I've got fewer than 50 reputations so that I cannot answer my own question until 8 hours has passed. I'll post my answer later when I can do that :P

Comment: @Zhiya fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've just resolved the problem. It turns out that I have to add one line:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

This works.